# MediaUriElement not displaying on win10 Enterprise edition

Tags: c#, wpf, wmv

I have a WPF aplication that uses **MediaUriElement** in order to display WMV clips, 
this application works just fine on most computers running Win10 Pro

However on Win10 Enterprise it simply does not show the WMV file, no error or exception simply blank window is displayed.

running the WMV file outside the WPF application works fine on Windows Media player or VLC player.

if I replace **MediaUriElement** with **MediaElement** - it works, 
but I have to use the MediaUriElement since I play the WMV file in 24/7 loop for days and the simple 
MediaElement leeks memory after a few days.

I installed:  K-Lite Codec Pack, directx , VLC  - nothing helped

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to find a difference between those computers? What about a freshly installed Win10?

Comment: my IT skills are poor so I can't detect the difference between the computers, all the computers are freshly installed Win10,  the difference between the computers is the image they are installed from -

Comment: What is the difference in those images?

Comment: I actually don't know, the computers are my company computers, I tried talking to the IT guys but they didn't seem to understand my problem.. so I was hoping someone will have an idea so I can go to the IT guys with more insight...

Comment: Tell them what images work and which not and ask them for differences...

Comment: I see the computer it works on is Win10 Pro, the computer it doen't work on is Windows 10 Enterprise, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could be the problem.

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790944/10871900

Comment: Did you try a fresh, standard win10 Pro/Enterprise installation?